# Select class and then select input in 3rd object in the list of classes in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I have my HTML as this

```
<div class="content">

    <section class="abc">
    <input type="text"/>
    <input type="text"/>
        ...
    <input type="text"/>

    </section>
    <section class="abc">...</section>
    <section class="abc">...</section>
    <section class="abc">...</section>
    <section class="abc">...</section>
    <section class="abc">...</section>

</div>
```

From the above code i need to select each section by number (like 0th ,1st) all inputs which is having null values

How to write jquery select for this ?

Comment: Have you try any code? if yes then please post first.

Comment: `$('input[value=""]')` ?

Comment: i tried this  var emptyTextBoxes = $(".abc(0) > " +'input:text[value=""]').filter(function() { return this.value == ""; });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
$('.content .abc:nth-child(1) input:visible').filter(function(){ return $.trim(this.value) === ''; });
```

I just gave `2n` for a demonstration purpose, since your question was unclear, But you can frame that according to your need.

Comment: @bpbhat77: Please don't lead the answerer on by asking bit by bit of your question, it makes for an unwieldy comment thread and wastes everyone's time. State all your requirements up front and list them in your question by editing.